# convert if statement to a ternary

Tags: if-statement, ternary

Heyo,

I need to convert this if statement to a ternary. I'm not very good with ternaries.. but I need to put this on a button on-click. I have to add a LOT more "ifs", but if I can get this converted to the right syntax I should be able to get the rest into it.

```
if (this.state.selectedMeat === 'Ham'){
  this.setState(this.state.calories = this.state.calories + this.state.meats[0].calories)
  }
  console.log('did calories go up?')
}
```

So I want the above if statement to work inside a button onclick ternary..

```
<button onClick={ 'the stuff goes here '} >Add Me Up!</button>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That code isn't really compatible with a ternary. It has no else case, and is just carrying out side effects. Both if those go against the entire purpose of a ternary. Just wrap it in a function to have something to put in the `onClick`.

Comment: Tried to make it a function to begin with, but then i couldnt get the function to have access to state. I tried writing the function inside the constructor, and the function seemed to run as soon as the page loaded rather than during the onclick. So I figured I could make it a ternary and put it into the button itself. I have quite a few more if statements to put into it.